# XTK lesson 13 (ami example) - Removing the boundary lines in slices obtained from 2D volume rendering

Tags: xtk, volume-rendering, ami.js

I've implemented XTK lesson 13 from the AMI examples (this - https://fnndsc.github.io/ami/#xtk_lesson13) by passing a set of DICOM images.

In the slices obtained, there are these colored dotted lines that I'm assuming is a boundary of some sort. I need to remove them but I'm not sure what exactly they are. Can someone tell me how they are created or what they represent?

Edit:

I'm not at liberty to post a screenshot from my implementation but this is a screenshot from the example url. Sorry the image isn't very clear, the example loads super small images. The slice is the image on the bottom.

[yellow dashed lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06IfT.png)

When you move the image (slice) around in the actual example, the yellow dashed lines appear on the image. That's what I need to get rid of. I've also been referring to them as dotted lines, I suppose they are actually dashed lines. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `stackHelper.slice.canvasWidth` and `stackHelper.slice.canvasHeight` to `0` for the dotted lines to disappear.

Those dotted lines are meant to inform that a part of the slice if partially off-canvas.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a stackHelper in the implementation. Is this something I have to initialize?

Comment: Oh OK maybe I misunderstood the problem, can you update your question with a screenshot that clearly shows the issue?